# For loop - sum all number - closed

Tags: c#, for-loop, sum

I want to add previous number and current number. Here have sample but with error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++)    
{    
    sumIdosage += Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]);

    // i want to sum all the dosage    
}

TxtBox5.Text = sumIdosage.ToString();

if (Convert.ToDecimal(TxtBox5.Text) < 100)    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Your Dosage is less than 100%");    
}
```

but at the end the answer are different as the image  dropbox.com/s/zav68w79hwa20ss/11.JPG?dl=0

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the sum are different from the formula as the image i share  dropbox.com/s/zav68w79hwa20ss/11.JPG?dl=0

Comment: The code itself looks fine. But why are you testing `TxtBox5` value? The if test for <100 should be against the `sumIdosage`, IMHO.  Also, debugger is your friend. Put a debug point on the line where the addition is happening, and look at how the variable state changes. Put up watches as well, and watch what's going on with the variable, with the value of the detail record, etc. It's the best (and fastest) way to solve this, when you think about it.

Comment: @code4life because dosage is %, so need to calculate 100% as formula. if below 100% need warning user.

Comment: Are you setting `sumIdosage = 0;` before starting this code?

Comment: @McAden yes, i did tried the result still same.

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, where does the value go awry?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] including all data necessary to reproduce problem inline. Also make sure to provide actual/expected results as text. (And indeed clarify why you can't use regular `Enumerable.Sum()` Linq method)

Comment: @ChengWan Also it looks like you've edited post to invalidate all answers - this is against SO recommendations. In particular this edit made accepted answer no longer answering question at all. Please keep that in mind for future questions/edit and possibly consider rolling back the invalid edit as part of writing [MCVE] for the question.

Comment: The other point is, I don't see any effort made to debug and understand the code. Without making the effort to to step through your code and understand what you've written, and how the variable states are affected, you're not going to make much progress as a programmer. I'm sorry to make this harsh point, but there it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're simply assigning the last value to `sumIdosage`, not adding anything anwhere.  You need to initialise `sumIdosage` to 0 before the loop, then do `sumIdosage += ...`

Also it makes no sense to convert the decimal to string, and back to decimal again:

```
TxtBox5.Text = sumIdosage.ToString();
if (Convert.ToDecimal(TxtBox5.Text) < 100)
```

Instead just do:

```
if (sumIdosage < 100)
```

Comment: if i use += the number will jumping from (i1)+(i2)=sum1 after that sum1+(i1)+(i2)+(i3)=sum2 and so on..

Comment: [`x += y`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew(v=vs.71).aspx) is short for `x = x + y`

Comment: yeah i know this logic, i'm using third party software to edit the program. i had no idea why it will become this. Those logic already correct to make user key-in, the main problem is the += logic.. any idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your example above `(i1)+(i2)=sum1 after that sum1+(i1)+(i2)+(i3)=sum2` is not correct.  `sum2` does not equal `sum1+(i1)+(i2)+(i3)`.  It just equals `(i1)+(i2)+(i3)`, or `sum1+(i3)`

Comment: Are you really asking to sum only the previous number and the current number? Your question asks one thing. Your code comment asks something completely different. Ian already explained how to get the overall sum of all numbers but if you need is different then you need to clarify.

Comment: bro check this image https://www.dropbox.com/s/zav68w79hwa20ss/11.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @TravisActon yes, i wish it could be easy and simple but maybe the third party make the code confuse.

Comment: If you have to write code through some third party interface and can't debug then Make the text box equal the detail count to see how many records are pulling (make sure it's 2). I bet your pulling more records than 2 because you need to be checking an active flag or something.

Comment: From the screenshot I can see the final value is 80 when it should be 50.  Did you make sure to initialise sumIdosage to 0?  Put `sumIdosage = 0;` directly above the for loop and try again.

Comment: @lan i tried just now. still the same. but you did help me a lot

Comment: The value of `sumIdosage` is being set _somewhere other_ than the loop.  Try and find all other places that variable is being used.

Comment: "You're simply assigning the last value to sumIdosage, not adding anything anywhere" - is completely false statement. OP definitely increments value on each iteration. Maybe they don't set it to 0 in the beginning, but without valid [MCVE] it is hard to know.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Now, yes.  But [when I wrote that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44837336/1), the code in the question said `sumIdosage = Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]);
`, which is why there are 2 other answers with the same instruction.

Comment: That's unfortunate - you may either update your answer to match the question or request OP to roll-back they changes. Answers that don't answer the question are not exactly useful.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True, but the code works now, so what is the question?  Should I delete my (accepted) answer because the OP updated the question with working code?

Answer (score 0):

```
sumIdosage += Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]);------
```

Comment: if i use += the number will jumping from (i1)+(i2)=sum1 after that sum1+(i1)+(i2)+(i3)=sum2 and so on..

Comment: @ChengWan that's incorrect, it will do (i1)+(i2)+(i3)+(i4)... for example, if the values are `[3, 2, 4, 8]` the first run will be `0 + 3`, the 2nd will be `3 + 2`, the 3rd will be `5 + 4`, the 4th will be `9 + 8`, your end result will be the correct value `17`

Comment: This is exactly the same code that is present in the question... Also complete lack of explanation makes it completely useless answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The original question has been modified after I post the answer here. That is why you see this is the same code. Please check the date and time before posting your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list to put all sums from the current and next like this:

```
List<Decimal> sumOfCurrPrev = new List<Decimal>();
for (int i = 0; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount-1; i++)    
{    
    sumOfCurrPrev.Add( Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"])+Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i+1).UDF["Dosage"]));
}
```

In the list are all sums. For example, in `sumOfCurrPrev[0]` is the sum of `Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(0).UDF["Dosage"])+Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(1).UDF["Dosage"])`, in `sumOfCurrPrev[1]` is the sum of `Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(1).UDF["Dosage"])+Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(2).UDF["Dosage"])` and so on

If you want the current and previous you can do this:

```
List<Decimal> sumOfCurrPrev = new List<Decimal>();
    for (int i = 1; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++)    
    {    
        sumOfCurrPrev.Add( Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i-1).UDF["Dosage"])+Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]));
    }
```

Comment: You'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, use `i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount - 1`

Comment: thank you ;) I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `+=` logic is correct. Assuming `e.MasterRecord.DetailCount` is what it appears to be, and `e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]` does what it appears to do it seems like there's really only 2 options.

Either:

1. The assumptions above are wrong
2. `sumIdosage` already contains some sort of value before you're starting your summation.

This **should** work

```
decimal sumIdosage = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < e.MasterRecord.DetailCount; i++)    
{    
    sumIdosage += Convert.ToDecimal(e.MasterRecord.GetDetailRecord(i).UDF["Dosage"]);
}

TxtBox5.Text = sumIdosage.ToString();
if (sumIdosage < 100)    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Your Dosage is less than 100%");    
}
```